# How do get host IPs from kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes, networking

When dual stack in use both IPv4/IPv6 how to get both status.hostIP currently primary address, how to get both IPv4 and IPv6 internally host IPs

env:
- name: NODE_IP
valueFrom:
fieldRef:
fieldPath: status.hostIP
Above is giving primary hostIP only, how to get the other IPs also configured on that host.

Comment: Hi sundeep welcome to SO. If you `kubectl get no -o yaml $the_node_name` do you see the IPv6 address anywhere in the `status:` fields? My _guess_ is that you're not going to get what you want in a dual-stack setup, but we'll start by seeing if the Node even provides the accounting

Comment: Currently we can see status.podIPs which provides both IPv4/IPv6 IP address, it would have been great if kubectl provides something similar for hostIp too.

Comment: Right, but what I'm asking is about the `status:` of the *Node* not the Pods. Since I don't have a dual-stack setup to check, I'm asking if *you* checked to see if there is a status field containing what you want. If not, there's your answer. If so, then we can work to find if the downward API allows access to it